# I can't open Tor on linux

Tags: configuration, linux

I am new to linux and am using Antergos with Deepin. I have installed Tor, but can't seem to open it. I tried from terminal, but get the following. Any advice?

```
Jul 17 21:10:27.072 [notice] Tor 0.3.3.9 (git-45028085ea188baf) running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.0h, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, and Libzstd N/A.
Jul 17 21:10:27.072 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jul 17 21:10:27.101 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Jul 17 21:10:27.135 [notice] Scheduler type KIST has been enabled.
Jul 17 21:10:27.135 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jul 17 21:10:27.135 [warn] Directory /var/lib/tor cannot be read: Permission denied
Jul 17 21:10:27.135 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't create private data directory "/var/lib/tor"
Jul 17 21:10:27.135 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Answer (score 1):

Tor will not start if it does not have the correct permissions for the directories its trying to use. It is telling you exactly what the problem is. It does not have permission to create the tor directory in /var/lib. Create the directory /var/lib/tor manually, and give it the correct permissions for the user tor is running under, usually named debian-tor.